# After adding SurfFeatureDetector, program giving error

Tags: c++, opencv, surf

I am using `opencv 3.3.0`

my code is

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/features2d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/xfeatures2d.hpp"
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
using namespace cv::xfeatures2d;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Mat img1;
    img1 = imread("img/img1.jpg", IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);

    if (img1.empty())
    {
        cout << "Could not open or find the image" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    Ptr<SurfFeatureDetector> detector = SurfFeatureDetector::create(400);
    vector<KeyPoint> keypoints;
    detector->detect(img1, keypoints);

    imshow("img1", img1);
    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

I am new to `C++` and `opencv`. The code work well without surf part.

error

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (TlsSetValue(tlsKey, pData) == TRUE) in cv::TlsAbstraction::SetData, file C:\Users\Darshana\Documents\opencv\opencv-3.3.0\modules\core\src\system.cpp, line 1270

I have tried with `Ptr<SURF> detector = SURF::create(400);` as well.

**UPDATE**

I couldn't figure out a solution for this. Maybe a setup issue or library issue. So I just move to `opencv 2.4.13` and now everything works fine. I had to change the above code to work with `v2.4.13` though.

Comment: If you down vote, please mention a reason.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't set parameter for `SurfFeatureDetector`. I think you should try this instead:

```
int minHessian = 400;
SurfFeatureDetector detector(minHessian);
vector<KeyPoint> keypoints;
detector.detect(img1, keypoints);
```

Comment: I already tried this. This won't work with `opencv 3.3.0`. It's giving compilation errors.

Comment: Oh, I use `opencv 2.4.13` and `SURF`, `SurfFeatureDetector`, `SurfDescriptorExtractor` is the same.